# Searching String List for FileName Match and Replace with new FilePath

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have got a `List<string>` called `Filelist`, it contains the *full paths* to files. I have another `List<string>` called `optimizelist` that also contains filepaths. I'm checking if `Filelist` contains the same file in `optimizelist`; if yes,then replace the corresponding element in `Filelist` with the element in `optimizelist`.

```
int x = 0;

foreach (string file in optimizelist)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Filelist.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Path.GetFileName(file) == Path.GetFileName(Filelist[i]))
        {
            Filelist.RemoveAt(x);
            Filelist.Add(file);

            break;
        }
     }

     x++;
}
```

But the replacement is not proper and there is *duplication* and *missing entries*.
What I'm i doing wrong? Please advice.

Comment: But why to replace you do remove+add? You can just do `Filelist[x] = file;`

Comment: @Evk okay ...Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing a list that you're iterating, which may cause unexpected behavior. You can avoid surprises by iterating it backwards (because changes are done at the current index and the end of the list, so never at lower indexes).

```
for (int i = Filelist.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Edit: you probably also want to remove the "break" statement. It prevents your code from iterating the full list.

Comment: Thanks.. this seems to have fixed the issue.The list contains no duplicate entries and is prescreened.So i think break is needed.. i guess,what do you think?

Comment: @techno If you're sure about there not being any duplicates, I guess you could keep the break statement.

Answer (score 1):

You are removing(in the middle) and adding (to the end) while you are enumerating the list. That's not a good idea and causes this issue. I'd suggest this approach to replace files:

```
var fileNameLookup = optimizelist.ToLookup(f => Path.GetFileName(f));
for (int i = 0; i < Filelist.Count; i++)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(Filelist[i]);
    var optimizedFile = fileNameLookup[fileName].FirstOrDefault();
    if(optimizedFile != null)
        Filelist[i] = optimizedFile;
}
```

Comment: @techno: just edited the answer to show you a better, more efficient approach

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Peter M. answer: if you don't have duplicates in `optimizelist` you can try using *dictionary*:

```
// key    - what to find (file name without directory, e.g. "abc.txt")
// value  - what to substitute (full path name, e.g. "c:\test\abc.txt") 
// StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase - case insensitive keys, i.e. "abc.txt" == "ABC.txt"
Dictionary<string, string> substitutes = optimizelist
  .ToDictionary(item => Path.GetFileName(item),
                item => item,
                StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

for (int i = 0; i < Filelist.Count; i++)
  // if we have a substitution (i.e. a better file path)...
  if (optimizelist.TryGetValue(Path.GetFileName(Filelist[i]), out var optimalFile))
    Filelist[i] = optimalFile; // <- substitute with optimalFile
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,optimizelist does not contain duplicates.What do you think about the break statement?

Comment: @techno: it should be any `break` in my version: you should scan every `file` in `Filelist` and substitute it if required. If you put break only *first* possible file in the `Filelist` will be optimized (imagine you have`Filelist [a, b,c ,d]`; without `break` you'll get `Filelist [a, B,C ,d]` - two files substituted, and with `break` - `Filelist [a, B,c ,d]` - only first one)

Comment: @techno: in my code only. In your code `break` is OK if `Filelist` doesn't have duplicates